# ASP.NET login page not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

When I login with user credentials, it continue even I select admin login type.. it should only continue when I select user login type.

Also when I login with admin credentials, it only shows the shwmssg error not redirecting to the dashboard. Please help me.

`web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="cs" 
             connectionString="Data Source= DESKTOP-F0L019J\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = EmploAid; Integrated Security= True; TrustServerCertificate=True" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="username" value="Admin" />
        <add key="password" value="123" />
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

`Login.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/User/UserMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmploAid.User.Login" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

     <section>
     <div class="container pt-50 pb-40">
                        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 pb-20">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" visible ="false"> </asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="contact-title text-center">Log in To EmploAid</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto ">
                    <div class="form-contact contact_form">
                        <div class="row">
                                                          <div class="col-12">
                                <h6>
                                    Login Information
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>
                                        Username
                                    </label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Desired Username" required ></asp:TextBox>
                                 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  
                                    <label>
                                          Password
                                     </label>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Desired Password" 
                                         TextMode="Password" required ></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            Login Type
        </label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLoginType" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control w-100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLoginType_SelectedIndexChanged"> <asp:ListItem Value="0">  Select Login Type  </asp:ListItem> 
                                                                                           <asp:ListItem>  Admin  </asp:ListItem> 
                                                                                           <asp:ListItem>  User  </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="UserType is Required"
    ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" Font-Size="Small" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddlLoginType" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>

          </div>
                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="button button-contactform boxed-btn mr-4 " OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                            <span class="c1ickLink">
     <a href="../User/Register.aspx">Want to Register? Click Here...</a>
 </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
 </section>
</asp:Content>
```

`login.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace EmploAid.User
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader sdr;
        string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
        string username, password = string.Empty;

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ddlLoginType.SelectedValue == "Admin")
                {
                    username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
                    password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];

                    if (username == txtUserName.Text.Trim() && password == txtPassword.Text.Trim())
                    {
                        Session["admin"] = username;
                        Response.Redirect("../Admin/Dashboard.aspx", false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showErrorMsg("Admin");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    con = new SqlConnection(str);
                    string query = @"Select * from [User] where Username = @Username and Password = @Password";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());

                    con.Open();
                    sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        Session["user"] = sdr["Username"].ToString();
                        Session["userID"] = sdr["userID"].ToString();
                        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showErrorMsg("User");
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void showErrorMsg(string userType)
        {
            lblMsg.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "<b>" + userType + "</b> Credentials Are Incorrect. ";
            lblMsg.CssClass = "alert alert-danger";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried typing Admin and 123 for username password because that's in my `web.config`, but nothing happens still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line if `if(ddlLoginType.SelectedValue == "Admin")` with if `if(ddlLoginType.SelectedValue.Trim() == "Admin")`. Because `ddlLoginType.SelectedValue` is returning the value as `" Admin "` not `"Admin"`.

Comment: you are God send. Thank you very muchh. Wish you all the best sir.

Comment: Is the accept answer the "check icon" if yes. I already did sir. I can't upvote for  now as I am new to here I'm sorry